# Query return duplicate items JPA nativeQuerry

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a native query who take multi criteria and sort.
It work well for the profile but when i do the same for company my query return duplicates items cause theire are multiple line for one user in my company table
my code :

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                "SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.nom, u.prenom, u.email, u.id_profil, p.code, c.name FROM exploitation.utilisateur u");
        sql.append(" inner join exploitation.profil p on p.id = u.id_profil");
        sql.append(" left join exploitation.company c on c.id_utilisateur = u.id");
        sql.append(" WHERE 1=1");

switch (utilisateurRequest.getTris().colonne()) {
            case "nom", "prenom", "email":
                sql.append(String.format(" ORDER BY u.%s %s ",
                                         utilisateurRequest.getTris().colonne(),
                                         utilisateurRequest.getTris().ordre().toLowerCase()));
                break;
            case "profils":
                sql.append(String.format(" ORDER BY p.code %s", utilisateurRequest.getTris().ordre().toLowerCase()));
                break;
            case "gestionnaire":
                sql.append(String.format(" ORDER BY c.name %s", utilisateurRequest.getTris().ordre().toLowerCase()));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

my user table contain a foreign key to profil, but does not contain any reference to the company table.

```
+--------------------+
| User               |
+--------------------+
| id                 |
| name               |
| id_profil          |
| ...                |
+--------------------+

+--------------------+
| Company            |
+--------------------+
| id                 |
| id_user            |
| name               |
+--------------------+

/// user 
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateurEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<UtilisateurGestionnaireEntity> utilisateurGestionnaire;
/// company 
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_utilisateur", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UtilisateurEntity utilisateurEntity;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

I can't transform my list to a set because i need the list size for pagination

`````
query.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<UtilisateurEntity> list = query.getResultList();````
`````